# I am trying to make my Java Android app give me admin permission for lock task mode but it fails

Tags: java, android, button, admin, deprecated

I have been trying to do lock task mode or lock into my app without being able to access other apps with still being able to disable the feature. I have looked at tutorials and documentation but some methods were deprecated since they were made around 5 years ago (onActivityResult). I have tried to change to the new methods (registerForActivityResult) that I found, however when I launch my app and try to enable admin permission by tapping on the enable button, the admin permissions don't pop up, so I cannot check it. So, when I try to lock my phone from other apps nothing happens because I don't have admin permissions.My Code for MainActivity.class below:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.myapplication.helper.MqttHelper;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallbackExtended;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button lock, disable, enable;
    private static final int RESULT_ENABLE = 11;
    private DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager;
    private ActivityManager activityManager;
    private ComponentName componentName;

    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    MqttHelper mqttHelper;
    //ChartHelper mChart;
    //LineChart chart;

    TextView dataReceived;
    private Button btnPublish;


    // Allowlist two apps.
    private static final String KIOSK_PACKAGE = "com.example.myapplication";
    private static final String[] APP_PACKAGES = {KIOSK_PACKAGE};

// ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        devicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        componentName = new ComponentName(this, Controller.class);

        lock = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lock);
        enable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enable);
        disable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disable);
        lock.setOnClickListener(this);
        enable.setOnClickListener(this);
        disable.setOnClickListener(this);

       
        
        dataReceived = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview_first);
        startMqtt();
    }




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        boolean isActive = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == lock) {
            boolean active = devicePolicyManager.isAdminActive(componentName);
            if(active) {
                devicePolicyManager.lockNow();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "You need to enable the Admin Device Features", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (view == enable) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, componentName);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,"You Should Enable the app!");
            //someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
            // Caller
            mGetContent.launch(intent);
            // Receiver

            //startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_ENABLE);
        } else if (view == disable) {
            devicePolicyManager.removeActiveAdmin(componentName);
            disable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            enable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }


    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Here, no request code
                        Intent data = result.getData();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK  && requestCode == RESULT_ENABLE){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


    /*@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode){
            case RESULT_ENABLE:
                if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK ){
                    //btn_unblock.setText("Dissable");
                    //btn_block.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }*/

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }



    // MQTT Code

    private void startMqtt(){
        mqttHelper = new MqttHelper(getApplicationContext());
        mqttHelper.mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallbackExtended() {
            @Override
            public void connectComplete(boolean b, String s) {
                Log.w("Debug","Connected");
            }

            @Override
            public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {

            }

            @Override
            public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                Log.w("Debug",mqttMessage.toString());
                dataReceived.setText(mqttMessage.toString());
                //mChart.addEntry(Float.valueOf(mqttMessage.toString()));
            }

            @Override
            public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

im currently working on an enterprise app which is running on a tablet which is also on lock task mode , so i shared what i have done for my case . is not a super clean code but its doing the job.

1st java class:

you need an admin receiver class like this

```
import android.app.admin.DeviceAdminReceiver;
public class AppAdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

}
```

its okay if u leave it empty.

2nd manifest.xml :

```
<receiver
        android:name=".AppAdminReceiver"
        android:description="@string/app_name"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

add this receiver to your manifest and edit label and description base on what u want.

and  you should set your app as admin via adb , cause i also couldn't enable it in settings so i currently use adb commands.

{packageName} : you can find packageName in gradle file tagged as "applicationId".

{your admin class} : your class might be like com.example.appName.AppAdminReceiver

```
// to set as owner/admin
adb shell dpm set-device-owner {packageName}/{your admin class}
// to remove owner/admin
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin {packageName}/{your admin class}
```

and last thing task lock class to make things easy :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.UserManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.isense.R;

public class KioskHandler {
    static ComponentName mAdminComponentName;
    static DevicePolicyManager mDevicePolicyManager;

    public static void startKiosk(Activity context){
       if(mDevicePolicyManager.isLockTaskPermitted(context.getPackageName())){
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (am.getLockTaskModeState() == ActivityManager.LOCK_TASK_MODE_NONE) {
                setDefaultCosuPolicies(true);
                context.startLockTask();
              
            }
        }
    }

    public static void stopKiosk(Activity context){
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (am.getLockTaskModeState() == ActivityManager.LOCK_TASK_MODE_LOCKED) {
            context.stopLockTask();
            setDefaultCosuPolicies(false);
           
            
        }
    }
    public static boolean initialize(Context context){
        try{
            mAdminComponentName = new ComponentName(context, AppAdminReceiver.class);
            mDevicePolicyManager = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            String[] packages={
                    context.getPackageName(),
                    "com.android.date",
                    "com.android.settings.date",
                    "com.android.bluetooth",
                    "com.bluetooth",
                    "com.Bluetooth",
                    "com.samsung",
                    "com.wifi",
                    "com.android.wifi",
                    "com.android.settings.bluetooth",
                    "com.android.settings.wifi"
            } ;
            mDevicePolicyManager.setLockTaskPackages(mAdminComponentName,packages);
            if(mDevicePolicyManager.isDeviceOwnerApp(context.getPackageName())){
                // App is whitelisted
                setDefaultCosuPolicies(true);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ignored){return false;}

    }

    private static void setDefaultCosuPolicies(boolean active){

        // Set user restrictions
        setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT, active);
        setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET, active);
        setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_ADD_USER, active);
        setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA, active);
        setUserRestriction(UserManager.DISALLOW_USB_FILE_TRANSFER,active);
        // Disable keyguard and status bar
        mDevicePolicyManager.setKeyguardDisabled(mAdminComponentName, active);
        mDevicePolicyManager.setStatusBarDisabled(mAdminComponentName, active);

    }

    private static void setUserRestriction(String restriction, boolean disallow){
        if (disallow) {
            mDevicePolicyManager.addUserRestriction(mAdminComponentName,restriction);
        } else {
            mDevicePolicyManager.clearUserRestriction(mAdminComponentName,restriction);
        }
    }
}
```

so let me explain these :

first u call initialize and pass the input it needs. then easily u can call stopKiosk or startKiosk to do your thing.

example :

```
KioskHandler.initialize(this);
KioskHandler.startKiosk(this);
// "this" has to be activity
```

NOTE :to install a new version or remove the app u must remove ownership of device with adb commands .